# How to use WiFi management API

Tags: firefox-os

My application on FF OS needs to configure SSA settings. For this I need to invoke WiFi management API provided by Mozilla. When I try to execute in my code I am getting error "Undefined Error ". Maybe i am not calling it correctly.

Comment: share what you have tried. then if you got stucked with some exact issue will help you. Refer this link for asking proper questions 
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Got this reply from Mozilla network: That is for internal applications only: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/d.../mozWifiManager

What this means: you need to include a permissions request in your manifest. " For prompt permissions, the user is prompted the first time the user accesses the related API, and has to make a choice prior to the API being granted."

However since this is internal only, this call is not available to developers. I do not know when this will become available.

Comment: @RashmiLaroia This will not become available in the future for **security reasons**. Just because it is possible to manipulate deep WiFi settings in Android, does not mean automatically, that it is a *good purpose* in general. However, feel free to file a bug at Bugzilla.

Answer (score 0):

> Powerful and dangerous APIs are **not available** to third-party apps.

Only **internal apps** can access the WiFi Management API on [[image]firefox-os](/questions/tagged/firefox-os), because they are intended for system-level apps and default apps created by Mozilla/operators/OEMs.

Check the [Permissions Table for Internal (Certified) Apps (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/App_permissions#Internal_(Certified)_app_permissions).